# Cannot read property 'scrollTo' of null in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-scrollview

I have a horizontal `ScrollView`, on which I wanted to have scroll functionality, where `onPress` it should scroll to right. I am using functional component.

Below is the snippets from my code:

```
const scroll = React.createRef();

<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{scroll.current.scrollTo({x: 0})}}}>

<ScrollView
horizontal={true}
showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
contentContainerStyle={styles.horizontalView}
 ref={scroll}
>

<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {scroll.current.scrollTo({x: 100})}}>
```

I saw above solution while I was searching for one. But this is giving me error:
`Cannot read property 'scrollTo' of null`.
I have been hitting my head for hours, but not able to do it. Please help.

Comment: We'd need to see your whole component to help. My best guess is that you are using a functional component right now, and you are referring to a scroll ref like it was a class component.

Comment: yes, it is a functional component. what changes should I make to make it work in functional component??

Answer (score 1):

You should use `useRef` as below:

```js
const scroll = useRef();
```